# Does a copied bitmap have the same options?

Tags: android, bitmap

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
            options.inPurgeable = true;
            Bitmap original = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    drawableid,options);
            Bitmap bm = original.copy(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, true);
            original.recycle();
```

In the above code are the option settings copied over as well when you call bitmap.copy?  That is Will bm have its inpurgeable set to true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the `BitmapFactory.Options` control the way that a `Bitmap` is generated. Once created, it is created once and for all so copying it will make an exact copy of the way it was created.